# cannot understand how to concatenate 2 string in a batch file using for loop

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 string in windows batch file and I want the n element from the first list will be assign to the n element from the second list

I want:

```
1A
2B
3C
```

what I've done is this:

```
FOR %%A IN (1 2 3) DO FOR %%B IN (A B C) DO ECHO %%A=%%B
```

but this create

```
1A
1B
1C

2A
2B
2C
.
.
.
```

which is clearly not what i need...
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as edit seems not to be posted, try this

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /A COUNTER=1
FOR %%A IN (A B C) DO (
  ECHO %%A!COUNTER!
  set /A COUNTER+=1
)
endlocal
```

Comment: question added in the post above

Comment: Deleted my post since this one is better. Thanks @elzooilogico for the edit though ;)